# redirect htaccess for facebook crawler

Tags: .htaccess, vue.js, web-crawler, facebook-share

I've created a SPA app with vuejs. Everything was perfect until I want to share dynamic content on Facebook.

After research I found that I need another file (In my case php file) when I fill the meta-tags for facebook crawler.
In htaccess I'm trying to detect to Facebook agents and to redirect to specific file to fill meta-tags.

This is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [NC,QSA]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Crawler
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Facebot|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule cars/carDetail(.*)$ http://website.api.com/v1.0/meta-tags$1 [R=301,L]
```

But is not working. When you try to debug from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/
url:

```
http://website.com/cars/carDetail?id=48
```

Is not redirecting to:

```
http://website.api.com/v1.0/meta-tags$1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my problem.

The redirect condition should be on the top of htaccess. Also I've add "RewriteBase /" option on the top:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

# allow social media crawlers to work by redirecting them to a server-rendered static version on the page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule cars/carDetail(.*)$ http://website.api.com/v1.0/meta-tags$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [NC,QSA]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}] 
</IfModule>
```